# Adding a new item to a collection using Fluent NHibernate doesn't INSERT the new row in the DB

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a model called `ShoppingLists` and each `ShoppingLists` has a collection of `ShoppingListItems` called `Items`.  What I would *like* to be able to do is add a new item to my list as such:

```
dbList.Items.Add(new ShoppingListItems(Guid.NewGuid(), identity.UserId, source.Raw));
```

I would expect the `ShoppingListItems` to automatically be *linked* to its parent `ShoppingLists` class, and for NHibernate to create the appropriate SQL `INSERT` statement when the transaction is committed.  However, instead I get the exception:

```
NHibernate.StaleStateException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146232832
  Message=Unexpected row count: 0; expected: 1
  Source=NHibernate
```

What I have to do instead is create the object, save it, then add it to the collection:

```
var newItem = new ShoppingListItems(Guid.NewGuid(), identity.UserId, source.Raw);
newItem.ShoppingList = dbList;
session.Save(newItem);
dbList.Items.Add(newItem);
```

I'd like to eliminate the need to do this.  My mappings for `ShoppingLists` is as such:

```
Id(x => x.ShoppingListId);

Map(x => x.UserId).Not.Nullable();
Map(x => x.Title).Not.Nullable();

HasMany(x => x.Items)
   .KeyColumn("ShoppingListId")
   .Cascade.Delete(); // If Shopping List is deleted, delete all the Items that reference this list
```

And my mappings for `ShoppingListItems` is:

```
Id(x => x.ItemId);

Map(x => x.Raw).Length(50);
Map(x => x.Qty);
Map(x => x.Unit);
Map(x => x.UserId).Not.Nullable();
Map(x => x.CrossedOut).Not.Nullable();

References(x => x.Recipe).Column("RecipeId");
References(x => x.Ingredient).Column("IngredientId");
References(x => x.ShoppingList).Column("ShoppingListId");
```

I've tried playing around with `Cascade.All()` on each, to no avoid.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is related to the `ShoppingListItem` *Guid* **ID** handling *(see the code snippets of the item creation in the question)*.

The "working" scenario, when the `ShoppingListItem` is created and persisted, does the following step - generates the `Guid` ID and passes it into the constructor

```
var newItem = new new ShoppingListItems(Guid.NewGuid()...)
```

Next, NHiberante is asked to do `session.Save(newItem)`, so the INSERT statement is issued...

But what will happen in the second case, when the `session.Save(newItem)` is not called, only `Add()` the item into the collection of the parent `ShoppingLists`?

As mentioned here: [5.1.4.7. Assigned Identifiers](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-id-assigned) (an extract)

> ...entities that use assigned generator cannot be saved via the ISession's `SaveOrUpdate()` method. Instead you have to explicitly specify to NHibernate if the object should be saved or updated...

What is NHibernate doing in this case (when the `session.Flush()` is called) is guessing: should be INSERT or UPDATE issued for each of the collection items?

When it comes to the `newItem`, it compares its `Guid` ID with the `UnsavedValue()`, which is in this case `Guid.Empty`.

> This comparison will result in a decision: Issue UPDATE statement, the Guid ID does not represent new object.

The UPDATE is executed. DB responds: Update done, *no errors, but also* **no** rows updated*. NHibernate throws:

> Unexpected row count: 0; expected: 1

#### Solution

Leave the GUID generation on the NHibernate. E.g.:

```
Id(x => x.ItemId)
  .GeneratedBy.GuidComb()
  .UnsavedValue(Guid.Empty);
```

And also, rather explicitly set the `newItem` reference to its parent, an optimize the cascade with Inverse() setting

```
// both assignments
newItem.ShoppingList = dbList;
dbList.Items.Add(newItem);
```

The list mapped with inverse:

```
// improved write operations handling
HasMany(x => x.Items)
   .KeyColumn("ShoppingListId")
   .Inverse()
   ...
```

Comment: I think you're on track with the generated GUIDs.  I've always set the value myself so I can keep track of it later, but I'll experiment with the `.GeneratedBy` syntax..  The `.Inverse()` thing I've never understood; doesn't that mean the shopping list item owns the relationship?  I'm not sure if this is what I want.

Comment: Ok this appears to almost work, with one problem.  When I call `dbList.Items.Add(newItem)`, then `newItem` doesn't link to `dbList`.  It has a `ShoppingListId` of `null`.  Shouldn't items added to a parent collection automatically link to that parent, or do I have to set this manually?  In which case, what if I don't know the ID of the parent since I'm creating both at the same time in a single transaction?

Comment: I have a feeling this has to do with my mappings in `ShoppingListItem` - Right now, it just has a single `References` to its parent `ShoppingList`.  Perhaps this needs a `OneToOne` mapping of some sort?

Comment: Confirmed with the NH mailing list, there's no way to do what I'm looking to do.  You absolutely *must* set the `ShoppingList` property of `newItem` when you add it.  It's common to write an `.Add()` method for `ShoppingList` to do this for you.

Comment: Sorry, for no response, it was my turn to sleep! ;) but you did it, great job. Do not give up to use NHibernate. Amazing tool ;) *NOTE: it is very good practice to always set both ways of relation in C#. Later, when loading NHibernate will do that for us. But in time of relation creation... it should be a MUST*

Answer (score 0):

please recheck the mappings for ShoppingListItems

You have to do a cascade all and inverse should be true

you have a bidirectional association between shoppinglist and item.

You may specify a bidirectional many-to-many association simply by mapping two many-to-many associations to the same database table and declaring one end as inverse.

Comment: I think the mapping is one to many.  There is one shopping list, which may contain many items.  A single item belongs to one and only one shopping list.